# How to make variable local to runtime loop in Python (potentially due to asyncio)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, local

I am currently making a discord bot using discord.py. Anyway, with my code, whenever I have a variable within an async loop, it gets (in my words) *applied globally*.

How do I make a variable exclusive to one runtime loop?

(observe the image below if you don't understand me, ignore the "Hey {}. You already have a game running", that's expected.)

[image: Example of bot in discord - ignore the bot name, I'm just using a test token]

The top is the pervious set of buttons, but I can interact with the bottom set of buttons by clicking the top set as they both share one list to store data.

Please help...
(Code shown below):

```
DiscordComponents(client)
compontentColours = [ButtonStyle.grey, ButtonStyle.grey, ButtonStyle.grey, ButtonStyle.grey,
                     ButtonStyle.grey, ButtonStyle.grey, ButtonStyle.grey, ButtonStyle.grey, ButtonStyle.grey]
matrix = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
disabled = [False, False, False, False,
            False, False, False, False, False]
label = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
components = returnButton(
    compontentColours, l=label, disabled=disabled)
embed = discord.Embed(
    title=f"Let's play Tic Tac Toe, {message.author.name}!", color=0x7fffd4)
await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
msgAwaitInfo = await message.channel.send('Select a square', components=components)
# Awaiting keypress
for _ in range(5):
    # Awaiting button click
    res = await client.wait_for("button_click")
    await res.respond(type=6)
    # Processing the matrix
    matrix[int(res.component.label)-1] = 'O'
    disabled[int(res.component.label)-1] = True
    compontentColours[int(res.component.label) -
                      1] = ButtonStyle.blue
    # Check if player has won
    iW = ifWon(matrix, lastMoveIndex=int(res.component.label)-1)
    if not not iW[0]:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title='{}'.format('Congratulations! You won, {}'.format(
                message.author.name)),
            color=0x008000
        )
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        disabled = [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
        if True: # Updating Matrix
            # Creating the matrix labels
            label = list(matrix[i] if matrix[i] != '' else str(i+1)
                 for i in range(0, len(matrix)))
            components = returnButton(compontentColours, label, disabled)
            await msgAwaitInfo.edit('Game Over.', components=components)
        return
    # The opponent's move - finding the best move for the bot
    if matrix.count('O') == 5:
        break
    iW =guarranteedWin(matrix, toPlay = 'X')
    if iW[0]:
        indx = cordsToIndx[iW[1][0][1:3]]
        matrix[indx] = 'X'
        compontentColours[indx] = ButtonStyle.blue
        label[indx] = 'X'
        disabled[indx] = True 
    else:
        while True:
            rand = randint(0, 8)
            if matrix[rand] == '':
                matrix[rand] = 'X'
                compontentColours[rand] = ButtonStyle.blue
                label[rand] = 'X'
                disabled[rand] = True
                break
            else:
                continue
    iW = ifWon(matrix, lastMoveIndex=rand)
    print(iW)
    if not not iW[0] and iW[1] == 'X':
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title='{}'.format('Oh no... you lost, {}'.format(
                message.author.name)),
            color=0xe32636
        )
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
        disabled = [True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
        if True: # Updating Matrix
            # Creating the matrix labels
            label = list(matrix[i] if matrix[i] != '' else str(i+1)
                 for i in range(0, len(matrix)))
            components = returnButton(compontentColours, label, disabled)
            await msgAwaitInfo.edit('Game Over.', components=components)
        return
    
    
    # Creating the matrix labels
    label = list(matrix[i] if matrix[i] != '' else str(i+1)
                 for i in range(0, len(matrix)))
    components = returnButton(compontentColours, label, disabled)
    await msgAwaitInfo.edit('Select a square', components=components)
```

Note some functions are just the AI for the tic tac toe

Thank you,
(and sorry for the lengthy code)

Comment: I'm not optimistic that you will get any answer to this question.  You've described a problem using, admittedly, your own terminology.  You've presented a long code listing that no one else can possibly run.  You need to either simplify to a working example or describe the problem with more specific terminology - preferably both.  The answer to your question might be in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0567/, but that's just a guess.